# Why does OE endleofan have "d"?

Tags: germanic-languages

Why does OE endleofan have "d"?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why it shouldn't?

Comment: @Draconis as far as I know the first part means one, OE an

Comment: Ah, so you're asking why there's a /d/ in there, when it's a compound of two roots that don't contain /d/? That's entirely answerable, but I'd suggest editing that into your question.

Comment: Should be asked at [english.se] instead.

Comment: @curiousdannii Does ELU handle Old English questions? I thought they were mostly focused on Modern English, and the /d/ has disappeared in the modern language.

Comment: @Draconis Yep they do. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/old-english

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It's only a partial answer : I'm not sure about the *why*** but I can give some details about the history of *endleofan*.

**You're right when you say the /d/ is recent:**

> "[In Proto-Germanic] 'eleven' and 'twelve' were compounds *aina-lif- [...] and
> *twa-lif- [...the] litteral meanings must originally have been *'one left over', *'two left over', but even the etymology of the second
> part is unclear"
>
> (Don Ringe, 2008, *From Proto-Indo-European to
> Proto-Germanic*, p. 205 (chapter 3, §3.4.5.ii))

**The /d/ appeared in some dialects (e.g. in West-Saxon), not in all Old English dialects:**

> "11. en(d)lefan, endleofan; Ru.¹ enlefan; Li. once ællef [...]"
>
> Campbell, 1974, *Old English Grammar*, §478 (p.282, chapter XVI)
>
> Ru.¹ stands for a Mercian text (Rushworth Gospels)
>
> Li stands for the Lindisfarne Gospels, circa +715

**The /d/ consonant is an epenthetic consonant which facilitates the pronunciation of /nl/.** This sound transformation belongs to the so-called "intrusion of consonants":

> "Intrusion of consonants occurs in a few forms only."
>
> "ml > mbl:" [...]
>
> "mt > mpt:" [...]
>
> "nl > ndl: W-S endleofan [...] beside enlefan"
>
> "nr > ndr:"
>
> "sl > stl:" [...]
>
> "sn > stn:" [...]
>
> "ls > lts:" [...]
>
> (Campbell, 1974, Old English Grammar, §478 (p.192, chapter IX))

**But why was this sound added?**

I'm not 100% sure but I can quote what Gaston Zink explained about the appearance of a /b/ in the Latin word 'núm(e)rum' > French 'nombre' (my translation);

> "The energetic articulation required by this unusual sequence on both side of the syllabic border [i.e. in nu**mr**um] then leads to a break in the plosive consonant: by anticipating the tension necessary for /r/, the finale of /m/ becomes stronger instead of weaker and becomes de-nasalized (under effort, the uvula rises again); the segmentation produces a /b/ that, with /r/, forms an explosive sequence."
>
> (Gastin Zink, 1986, *Phonétique historique du français*, pp. 45-46, text slightly modified)
>
> [original text : see note a]

For *endleofan*, please notice that /n/ and /d/ are both dental consonants. **The same reasoning applies to this word.**

---

[note a]

> "L'articulation énergique que requiert cet enchaînement insolite de part et d'autre de la frontière syllabique [nu**mr**um] entraîne alors une brisure de la consonne implosive : par anticipation de la tension nécessaire pour le /r/, la finale de /m/ se renforce au lieu de s'atténuer et se désanalise (sous l'effort, la luette se relève); la segmentation produit un /b/ propre à former avec /r/ une suite explosive."
>
> (Gastin Zink, 1986, Phonétique historique du français, pp. 45-46; text slightly modified)

Comment: Why do you think it's partial though? You addressed the most important issues, "The /d/ consonant is an **epenthetic** consonant which **facilitates** the pronunciation of /nl/" and "The /d/ **appeared in some dialects** (e.g. in West-Saxon), not in all Old English dialects" - and that's *all* that matters.

Comment: @AlexB. : this sound change appears in a certain context, for example related to the position of the tonic accent. I don't know the exact phonetic value of the word *endleofan*, hence my cautious remark. Feel free to complete my answer!